# Laravel recaptcha not rendering

Tags: laravel, recaptcha

I am using [this package](https://github.com/albertcht/invisible-recaptcha) to add recaptcha in my laravel app, and when I add `@captcha` to my view it just print as is without rendering any captcha or badge.

Did anyone had the same issue with this package? how to fix it?

Comment: what version of laravel are you using? what version of that package?

Comment: @lagbox solved my issue and shared the link. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I've changed my package to [this one](https://packagist.org/packages/irando/invisible-recaptcha) which is based on my question package and also supports laravel 8 now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

in .env you have this?:

```
INVISIBLE_RECAPTCHA_SITEKEY={siteKey}
INVISIBLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRETKEY={secretKey}
```

and make sure **siteKey** and **secretKey** is right.

after you add this to .env try run:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Do you see any error in console?

Comment: clear config didn't help, and no i don't have any error in console

Comment: Ok so, you siteKey and secretKey is right.. yes? 
@captcha is in form element?

Comment: @mafortis or if you can please update your post here with more details... Laravel version, some code where you have tag captcha, env file with lines siteKey and secretKey with some fake numbers...